# How to generate CSV file for polygons to show in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, csv

My table looks like this:
[image: but adding this as a text defined layer hasn't got me anywhere]

but adding this as a text defined layer hasn't got me anywhere as X and Y are not clearly defined.

I am new to QGIS.

Comment: This looks like a Geojson file. Try to use that format in QGIS.